# Place JPanel inside of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have been at this for hours now, and I am stumped. I have this code, which adds a JPanel within a JFrame and the issue is when I have the Frame set to `Free Design` It doesn't show up in the Frame. When I set the Frame to `Border Layout` the code works fine. What I would like to do is get this to work with `Free Design` where I can place and resize the JPanel as I please. Here is the following code that places it in the Frame.

```
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setVisible(true);
        canvas.setImage(file);
        GroupLayout canvasLayout = new GroupLayout(canvas);
        canvas.setLayout(canvasLayout);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        //canvas.setSize(200,200);
        //canvas.setPreferredSize(null);
        add(canvas);
        revalidate();
```

When I use free design mode, what am I missing? Here is the code that builds the layout:

```
private void initComponents() {

    jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();

    jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("PocketShop");
    setName("main");

    pack();
}
```

Comment: You need to supply constraints to the group layout manager so that it knows where and how you want the component to be laid out. Have a look at [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) - Note, `GroupLayout` is intended to be used by form designers and wasn't meant for hand coding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do away with JInternalFrame**

JInternalFrame is for children inside a JDesktopPane. A kind windows in windows, the so called MDI, multi-document-interface, as opposed to SDI, single-document interface.

**Use JPanel instead of Canvas**

Canvas is of the old native platform AWT, a Component, JPanel of Swing, a JComponent.
You can there override paintComponent.

For the Free Design layout, I would use a GUI editor as in the NetBeans IDE. I do, and so cannot help you further there.

Do not use revalidate if possible.

---

If you manually add the Canvas, try adding a JPanel, and set as custom creation code `new Canvas()` or `canvas`.

Comment: The canvas is my custom class, which extends JPanel. That second section of code was built by my editor with Netbeans GUI Builder, and It won't let me change it.

Comment: In this case it looks you are still constructing the GUI, and then revalidate is at least superfluous. Unfortunately that JInternalFrame is not the error. JInternalFrame is added a bit irregular to the JDesktopPane: error prone. I will add to the answer.